# Integral of hyperbolic and ordinary trigonometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Recently I have proved that

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{\cos\left[\lambda x\right]}{\cosh^{2}x}=\frac{\pi\lambda}{\sinh\left[\pi\lambda/2\right]}
\end{equation}

Now I would like to get an integral result for a slight more complicated formula, given by

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{\cos\left[\lambda x\right] \cos[\Lambda x^2]}{\cosh^{2}x}
\end{equation}

Do you know any tricks or hints for where I should start? Or does this equation have an analytical result? I have tried looking within integral tables, but I could not find this integral in particular. Mathematica also did not give me any answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica is not that great with hyperbolic functions. Try writing $cosh(x)$ as $\frac{e^x  + e^{-x}}{2}$ and see if that gets a result.

Comment: No, I do not get any result. Actually, if I change cosh by the exponential, I cannot even obtain the first equation of my post.

Comment: I would express your first result as the Fourier Transform of $1/\mathrm{cosh}x^2$ and the use convolution theorem for the Inverse Fourier Transform, the normal trig identity for $\cos x^2$ and a table of Fourier transforms to find the result. Although it might not work.

Comment: If it was $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left[\lambda x\right] \cos[\Lambda x]}{\cosh^{2}x}\,dx$$ the result is quite nice. With $\Lambda x^2$, ???

Comment: For arbitrary $\Lambda$ there could not be a concise answer. This type of integrals can be obtained in the closed form only for specific values of $\Lambda$. For evaluation the complex integration is being usually used. Integrand is modified in a special way (to present the initial integral as difference of two integrals in the complex plane. There are examples of such integration at StackExchange and AoPS (for example, one of the typical integrals and solutions - https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2585782p22384158 )

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the answer has a very nice connection with quantum mechanics, see below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If written cleverly, this has a very surprising connection to quantum physics. Let's denote

$$I[\Lambda,\lambda] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos[\lambda x]\exp[i\Lambda x^2]}{\cosh^2x}dx$$

where the integral we want is $\operatorname{Re}\{I[\Lambda,\lambda]\}$. Taking derivatives, we have

$$\partial_\Lambda I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ix^2\cos[\lambda x]\exp[i\Lambda x^2]}{\cosh^2x}dx$$

$$\partial_\lambda^2I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-x^2\cos[\lambda x]\exp[i\Lambda x^2]}{\cosh^2x}dx$$

$$\implies i\partial_\Lambda I = \partial_\lambda^2 I$$

In other words, $I$ is a solution to the Schrodinger equation (for a $1$D free particle) where $\Lambda$ plays the role of a time variable. This has a known solution in the form of the time evolution operator $U[\Lambda]$ for a time-independent Hamiltonian

$$I[\Lambda,\lambda] = U[\Lambda]I[0,\lambda] = \exp\left[-i\Lambda \partial_\lambda^2\right]\frac{\pi \lambda}{\sinh\left[\frac{\pi \lambda}{2}\right]}$$

We could go even further and simplify this expression for our integral

$$\operatorname{Re}\{I[\Lambda,\lambda]\} = \cos\left[\Lambda \partial_\lambda^2\right]\frac{\pi \lambda}{\sinh\left[\frac{\pi \lambda}{2}\right]}$$

meaning the first term to even appear as a correction would be a fourth derivative of the expression.

Comment: So nice and simple ... after reading the solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for the kind words!

Comment: They are not kind. This part of my philosophy after more than sixty years in research : if something is nice, I tell it. Cheers and thanks for always providin nice answers and comments. Cheers :-)

Comment: A clever operator approach! (+1)