# Integral of involving hyperbolic and ordinary trigonometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I am wondering whether I can obtain a closed form solution for the following integral

\begin{equation}
I(n,\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos[\lambda(x+x_0)^n]}{\cosh^2x}dx,
\end{equation}
with $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x_0,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. I must say that for $n=1$ we can resolve it by using

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{\cos\left[\lambda x\right]}{\cosh^{2}x}=\frac{\pi\lambda}{\sinh\left[\pi\lambda/2\right]}
\end{equation}

For $n=2$, we can use the trigonometry identities, and rewrite $I(2,\lambda)$ as
\begin{equation}
\propto\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\frac{\cos\left[\lambda x\right]\cos[\Lambda x^2]}{\cosh^{2}x}
\end{equation}
which is shown to be expressed as a series by a nice post [@Ninad Munshi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304520/integral-of-hyperbolic-and-ordinary-trigonometric-function).

I am now trying to generalize it, but I am now being able to find a cleaver way to do so.
Initially I was thinking about rewriting the $\cos[\lambda(x+x_0)^n]$ as a series and integrate term by term, but this is very impractical. Secondly, I also thought about solving the integral using complex analyzes, i.e., solving

\begin{equation}
{\cal I}(n,\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp[{i\lambda(x+x_0)^n}]}{\cosh^2x}dx,
\end{equation}
and then evaluating $I(n,\lambda)=\rm{Re}[{\cal I}(n,\lambda)]$. Any thoughts?